# MongoDB better way of searching through collections for key

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to see if my `string` is in a specific `key` in my whole collection.

Example of collection:

```
_id: "XXX"
hwid: "XX1"

_id: "XXX"
hwid: "XX2"

_id; "XXX"
hwid: "XX3"
```

I want to search through all of the `hwid` keys in my collection and see if my `string` is in one of them and then return true/false. I thought it'd be a good way to do this with a for loop but it returns false everytime

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("connection works")
db = client.monza
collection = db.whitelist

def search_hwid(hwid):
    for x in collection.find({}, {"hwid"}):
        if hwid == x['hwid']:
            whitelisted = True
            return whitelisted
            break
        else:
            whitelisted = False
            return whitelisted
```

it returns `False` everytime even when I am 100% sure that `hwid` is in my collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//please see outcomes of find option with various options, for your query you need to find directly
//without using {} as first parameter
> db.test3.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "hwid" : "XX1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "hwid" : "XX2" }
{ "_id" : 3, "hwid" : "XX3" }
> db.test3.find({},{hwid:"XX2"});
{ "_id" : 1, "hwid" : "XX1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "hwid" : "XX2" }
{ "_id" : 3, "hwid" : "XX3" }
> db.test3.find({hwid:"XX2"});
{ "_id" : 2, "hwid" : "XX2" }
> db.test3.find({hwid:"XX3"});
{ "_id" : 3, "hwid" : "XX3" }
```